# Spring Boot - WebClient - multipart response - How to get the binary data

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, multipartform-data, spring-webclient

Here is my code to call a REST-Service

```
 String result = webClient.post()
                .body(BodyInserters.fromMultipartData(bodyBuilder.build()))
                .exchangeToMono(clientResponse -> clientResponse.bodyToMono(String.class))
                .block();
```

This works fine. I get a HTTP-Status 200.

**Response**

*Header Content-Type*: multipart/form-data; boundary="n1OnMVB:z)VeTRs)kd9:h8Hz9H+_kywMV2mb)MWu."

*Body*

```
--n1OnMVB:z)VeTRs)kd9:h8Hz9H+_kywMV2mb)MWu. Content-Disposition: form-data; name="lastname"

smith
--n1OnMVB:z)VeTRs)kd9:h8Hz9H+_kywMV2mb)MWu. Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data"; filename="data.cms" Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

0�  *�H�� ��0�
```

Problem/Question: How can i receive the binary data. I need something like that

```
byte[] result = webClient.post()....... -> clientResponse.bodyToMono(byte[])
```

Or even better

```
MyResultObject result = webClient.post().....-> clientResponse.bodyToMono(MyResultObject.class)
```

Where MyResultObject has the corresponding members.

I tried many. I searched a lot. But i found unfortunately nothing what helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found a solution. I first tried it with RestTemplate. Same problem, i found no solution to access the binary data.

I found a working solution without REST. I use httpClient directly.

```
 CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
 InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(response.getEntity().getContent());
 ByteArrayDataSource datasource = new ByteArrayDataSource(in, "multipart/form-data");
 MimeMultipart multipartR = new MimeMultipart(datasource);
 BodyPart bodyPart = multipartR.getBodyPart(1); //Or you can iterate about the body parts
 InputStream is = bodyPart.getInputStream());
```

Answer (score 1):

There is now a way to do it via **Spring Flux** webclient and using the [DefaultPartHttpMessageReader](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/codec/multipart/DefaultPartHttpMessageReader.html) class

First we would need the reader

```
final var partReader = new DefaultPartHttpMessageReader();
partReader.setStreaming(false);
```

And then make the call via weblcient

```
WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder().build();
ResponseEntity<Flux<Part>> request = webClient
                .get()
                .uri("...")
                .accept(MediaType.MULTIPART_MIXED)
                .retrieve()
                .toEntityFlux((inputMessage, context) ->
                        partReader
                                .read(ResolvableType.forType(byte[].class), inputMessage, Map.of()))
                .block();
```

Once we execute the request, we will get `Flux<Part>` as response with each part being the individual parts of the multipart response.

`part.headers()` will give you the headers and `part.content()` will give you the actual content in [DataBuffer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/buffer/DataBuffer.html) format. For eg, if you want to extract an image from the response and send it in bytes, you can do this :

```
            byte[] image = null;
    
            List<Part> parts = request.getBody().collectList().block();
    
            for (Part part : parts) {
                // access individual parts here
                System.out.println(part.headers());
                if (part.headers().get("Content-Type").get(0).equals("image/jpeg")) {
                    image = DataBufferUtils.join(part.content())
                            .map(dataBuffer -> {
                                byte[] bytes = new byte[dataBuffer.readableByteCount()];
                                dataBuffer.read(bytes);
                                DataBufferUtils.release(dataBuffer);
                                return bytes;
                            }).block();
                }
            }
return image;
```