# Spring WebClient. Receive multipart/form-data

Tags: java, spring, reactive, spring-webclient

There is existing `BodyExtractors` for multipart/form-data for using with WebClient.

I found:

1. Solution to send multipart/form-data via WebClient;
2. Solution to read multipart/form-data in Controllers. (`BodyExtractors.toMultipartData()`)

But I can't find the solution to parse multipart response body by WebClient.

Comment: What do you mean by "parse multipart response body by WebClient". Try to give an example.

Comment: OP means `org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter` only writes, but not reads `multipart/form-data` and `multipart/mixed` media types, as stated in it's documentation.

Comment: Answered on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65896940/spring-boot-webclient-multipart-response-how-to-get-the-binary-data/73973725#73973725

Comment: Answered on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65896940/spring-boot-webclient-multipart-response-how-to-get-the-binary-data/73973725#73973725

Answer (score 1):

You must register it as a custom codec directly with the `WebClient`.

For example, in your WebClient bean:

```
return WebClient.builder()
        .codecs(clientCodecConfigurer -> clientCodecConfigurer.defaultCodecs().maxInMemorySize(1 * 1024 * 1024)) // How to change defaults
        .codecs(clientCodecConfigurer -> clientCodecConfigurer.customCodecs()
            .register(new MultipartHttpMessageReader(new DefaultPartHttpMessageReader())) // <-- Add this custom codec
        )
        .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE) // How to set default header
        .baseUrl("https://foo.local") // How to set Base URL in builder
        .build();
```

This registers the [`MultipartHttpMessageReader`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/codec/multipart/MultipartHttpMessageReader.html) for this `WebClient`.

If you only have a WebClient instance prefabricated, you can still mutate it:

```
MultiValueMap<String, Part> response = webClient
  .mutate() // This creates a pre-initialized builder
  .codecs(clientCodecConfigurer -> clientCodecConfigurer.customCodecs()
      .register(new MultipartHttpMessageReader(new DefaultPartHttpMessageReader())) // <-- Add our codec
  )
  .build() // Build a new instance
  .get() // Whatever is your HTTP method
  .accept(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
  .retrieve()
  .bodyToMono(new ParameterizedTypeReference<MultiValueMap<String, Part>>() { 
      /* Freeze generic types. You need the exact type, as the Codec looks into the key and value types as well. */ 
  })
  .block();
```

This way, you can keep the values from the previous builder (e.g., OAuth2 filters).